# dealing with raw vector from r getURLContent

Tags: r, vector, utf, rcurl, geturl

I am using `getURLContent(url, userpasswrd, httpauth=1L, binary=TRUE)` to download a csv file from a server.

The data I get after using this getURLContent () is a raw vector with contents

```
"4d" "43" "4e" "2c" "45" "4e"
```

I know the dataset should have arround 400 columns and few hundred rows. How do I convert this raw vector to into appropriate data. I have used

```
as.raw(as.hexmode(rawvector1)
rawToChar(iconv(rawvector1, from="UTF-8"))
```

None of these work. Basically I dont know how to convert raw vector to the right format. Any help here is much appreciated.

Okay I tried this approach and it worked.

```
test1 = getURLContent(url,userpwd,httpauth = 1L, binary=TRUE) 
testraw1= readBin(test1 , what='characer', n=length(t61)/4) 
new.dataframe = data.frame(read.csv(textConnection(testraw1)))
```

Comment: Can you not just use `read.csv()`?

Comment: @RichardScriven, when I try `read.csv` i get an error `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection` when I try `read.csv(textConnection(rawvector1))`, i get an error Error in `textConnection(rawvector1) : invalid 'text' argument`

Comment: No i meant read.csv directly from the url

Comment: @RichardScriven, tried that as well , `read.csv("....\test.csv")` shows `cannot open: HTTP status was '400 Bad Request' error` I tried `readChar(rawVector1, 3)`. I was able to read just the 1st column name "IdN" thats it...there are so  400 columns with varying column name length and data element , looks like UTF-8 encoding issue

Comment: How about `httr`? `GET(url, authenticate(user, passwd), write_disk("file.csv"))` then `read.csv` or no `write_disk()` and use `content(result, as="text")`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I tried this and it worked ,                                                               `test1 = getURLContent(url,userpwd,httpauth = 1L, binary=TRUE)
        testraw1= readBin(test1 , what='characer', n=length(t61)/4)
        new.dataframe = data.frame(read.csv(textConnection(testraw1)))`